# How to Manage Service Location in BPEL process file

Tags: soa, esb, bpel

I have create a bpel process and able to invoke the service successfully.

But, I am mentioning location of service in WSDL as shown below

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8081/service_sample/services/multiplySoapPort" />
```

If there is a change in location, do I need to change the wsdl file?

or is there any other way to handle this situation?

I am new bee to SOA world, BPEL, ESB. what am I missing to learn and apply here?

Question might sound silly for experts, But still wondering how to overcome this problem.

I am using JBoss SOA Platform 5.2. (BPEL is same for all vendors).

Answer (score 2):

BPEL itself only uses the platform-independent part of the WSDL: A partnerlink refers to a partnerlink type which refers to porttype (not services!) The definition of which service to actually call is outside of the BPEL standard and part of the deployment. JBoss uses a customized version of Apache ODE AFAIK. For an ODE deployment descriptor you specify a port and a service in the deployment. The engine takes the endpoint directly from the service element.

If you want to be more flexible for changing the endpoint later on, you have two choices:

1. Use some form of ESB (with this I do not necessarily mean a high-end product, although you can use it. In some projects we also use a small Apache Camel Wrapper...): The ESB layer provides so-called Endpoint Transparency: In the process deployment you configure the process to call the ESB layer which in turn does call the actual service (routing). If the actual service's location changes you can change your routing rules in the ESB and leave the BPEL process and all other consumers alone.
2. In the BPEL file assign the endpoint directly to the partner link. If it is only about configuation, I would not prefer this solution. You need to read the endpoint location from anywhere and  it to the partnerlink. The XML you need to assign to the partnerlink is something like this:

   <sref:service-ref xmlns:sref="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/serviceref">
   <EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
       <Address>YourNewEndpoint</Address>
   </EndpointReference>
   </sref:service-ref>

Hope this helps!

Update:
Here is a complete assign activity as requested in the comment (I cannot add this in the comment somehow):

```
<bpel:assign>
   <bpel:copy>
     <bpel:from>
       <bpel:literal>
         <sref:service-ref xmlns:sref="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/serviceref">
           <EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
             <Address>YourNewEndpoint</Address>
           </EndpointReference>
         </sref:service-ref>
       </bpel:literal>
     </bpel:from>
     <bpel:to partnerLink="YourPartnerLink"/>
   </bpel:copy>
</bpel:assign>
```

Comment: First option is like have a proxy for all the services and use the proxy to invoke the service from BPEL (for orchestration), if there is any change in real endpoints. Then, change the details in ESB layer. Is this what you mean?. Assume, If I use JBOSS FUSE ESB, I can proxy all the service and use as you advised.

Comment: Can I do any thing with UDDI. I need to learn that first anyways.

Comment: Yes, define a proxy service e.g. in JBoss Fuse and proxy the services. The proxy will just be a router, i.e. the message will travel unchanged through the ESB.

Comment: UDDI is pretty dead. I don't know whether it is or can be integrated into the WSO2 Process Engine.